# Intellij Ide color scheme Grayed out by General text color

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Ide 2021.3 (ultimate edition) to learn spring boot. My issue is that the color scheme for all code "except keywords" appears grayed out by using the default text color. despite checking and unchecking all the inherit values from "checkbox" in language defaults and in java and changing the color scheme and editor theme multiple times this issue persists. What's confusing is that whenever I hover on a line of code it appears to be perfectly colored in the tooltip according to the color scheme that I chose. Am new to Intellij Ide and I could really use your help here. I reverted To the Dragula theme and color scheme to display the issue in a more simplified setup. [grayed out code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDK6f.png) [correctly colored in tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8C19.png) [grayed out code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evwzj.png) [correctly colored in tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fykg2.png). Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is not with color scheme but with [Content Roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html):

[image]

Try to open Maven tool window and click on `Reload All Maven Projects`:

[image]

or mark the sources/test roots manually by right clicking on `main/java` and `test/java` and selecting the appropriate option under `Mark Directory As`.

Comment: Thank you Egor for your help.I got no results when I did "Reload All Maven Projects". The Mark directory as source only made the annotations colored. So I went ahead and made a simple java project and as you can see the source folder is already marked but I still get the class names grayed out. Also, I want to get rid of the unused variables grayed out as well. and thank you for your time, sir. ![Java project image](https://imgur.com/dwCVkhA).